# ssh -T git@gtihub.com command does not show passphrase on my Ubuntu20.04

Tags: git, github, ssh

On Ubuntu 20.04, I tried cloning GitHub repository.(git clone (ssh url))

> git clone git@github.com:scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git

But "git clone" command does not work.
When I git clone repository (ssh), **terminal does not ask passphrase of ssh.**

I thought that ssh does not work on my PC, **so I tried ssh -T git@github.com.
It did not work.**

When I tried ssh git@github.com, **terminal did not ask passphrase, but it did work.**

What is the problem with my git and ssh?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a private key protected by a passphrase, then, [as described here](https://kamarada.github.io/en/2019/07/14/using-git-with-ssh-keys/), make sure it is added to the agent first:

```sh
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then you can test it with ssh -T git@github.com, provided you have registered the public key forst to your [GitHub account SSH section](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

Comment: @ekusiadadus Is your private key protected by a passphrase? Did you add it to the agent? What error message did you get?

Comment: My private key seems protected by passphrase. But only once I've asked to enter passphrase.

Comment: @ekusiadadus OK, add it first to the ssh agent.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: @ekusiadadus Can you try with a key *not* protected with a passphrase?

Comment: What is a key not protected with a passphrase ? All of the ssh keys are protected with passphrase.

Comment: @ekusiadadus no, not *all* ssh keys are passphrase protected. You can leave the passphrase empty when defining a new key.